# Why does "extern const int n;" not work as expected?

Tags: c++, constants, declaration, extern

My project consists of only two source files:

a.cpp:

```
const int n = 8;
```

b.cpp:

```
extern const int n;

int main()
{
    // error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const n" (?n@@3HB)
    int m = n; 
}
```

I know there are several methods to make it work; however, I just wonder WHY it does't work?

Comment: Try changing `a.cpp` to `extern const int n = 8;` AFAIK `const` implies `static`, although I don't really know.

Comment: Does a.cpp need to see the decleration of n with the extern keyword?

Comment: You didnt tell us what you link and how...

Comment: Yup, it implies internal linkage.

Comment: @Joachim, Yes. I compiled and linked them together.

Comment: If these were c files compiled with gcc it would work fine. There's no reason to have this tagged C

Comment: Put the `extern const int n;` in a.h and include that in both cpp files.

Comment: @Bo, I just wonder why that doesn't work rather than how to make it work.

Comment: @xmllmx - In C++ (but possibly not in C) a `const int` is the same as a `static const int`. This means that the value in a.cpp isn't visible outside that file, so b.cpp can't see it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's because `const` implies internal linkage by default, so
your "definition" isn't visible outside of the translation unit
where it appears.

In this case, by far the best solution is to put the declaration
(`extern int const n;`) in a header file, and include that in
both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`.  The linkage is determined by the
first declaration the compiler sees, so the later definition in
`a.cpp` will have the correct (external) linkage.

Alternatively, you can force the linkage in the definition:

```
extern int const n = 8;
```

Despite the `extern`, this is still a definition; anything with
an initializer outside of a class definition is a definition.

Answer (score 11):

`const` and `constexpr` variables in C++ have internal linkage (and thus aren't accessible in other compilation unit) if they aren't also declared `extern` (either in the definition or in a previous declaration).

In C, it isn't the case (well C hasn't `constexpr`) so your code is valid, and more you can put `extern` on a definition.

So if you want to write code which is both C and C++ (and the two declarations should probably come from the same header as James pointed out):

```
// a.cpp
extern const int n;
const int n = 8;

// b.cpp
extern const int n;

int main()
{

    int m = n; 
}
```

if you don't

```
// a.cpp
extern const int n = 8;
```

is also possible

Answer (score 3):

Declare it extern in a.cpp and just use without extern in b.cpp:

a.h

```
extern const int n ;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
...
const int n= 8
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
...


int main()
{        
    int m = n; 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, used to do this with a header file. Including the header with the extern is the simplest way.

Comment: Actually, you should *remove* `const int n;` from b.cpp. The included header is whats needed.

Answer (score 2):

`To share a const object among multiple files, you must define the variable as extern.`

```
To define a single instance of a const variable, we use the keyword extern on both its definition and declaration(s):
```

From these rules you just need to add the `extern` keyword in your definition. you already have it in declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers here do not do the trick, it may be the case that you have your definitions in different namespaces... if the compilation passes, and you get an `undefined symbol` linker error:

- check the namespace of the undefined symbol; that's the effective namespace for the     `extern const int n` declaration.
- ensure that's your effective namespace where you make the `const int n = 8` definition.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, with ***extern const***, but I tried using ***#define*** and it worked.

I think that declaring a **constant** as a **variable** should not be a very recommended practice, perhaps it could happen that someone tries to change the value of the variable and ends up corrupting something.

From what I understand, the use of ***extern*** is to find variables in source files (*.c/*.cpp), when only the header (*.h/*.hpp) is included.

header1.hpp file:

```
#define abc 1
```

source2.cpp file:

```
#include "header1.hpp"
```

It might be good to remember to use [include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files):

```
#ifndef _HEADER1_HPP_
#define _HEADER1_HPP_
#include "main.hpp"

#define abc 1

#endif // #ifndef _HEADER1_HPP_
```