# Undefined reference issue with a minimal "extern" usage test case

Tags: c++, linker, extern

My test case has two files:

a.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const string program_name("myprog");
```

b.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern const string program_name;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << program_name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I'm getting the following output:

```
$ g++ -c a.cc -o a.o -std=c++11 -O2
$ g++ -c b.cc -o b.o -std=c++11 -O2
$ g++ a.o b.o -o case
b.o: In function `main':
b.cc:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `program_name'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In a.o, I have the following symbol:

```
0000000000000018 b _ZL12program_name
```

And in b.o:

```
         U program_name
```

The question is: why I'm shooting myself in the foot here?

Note: **g++ 4.9.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good one. It's all due to `const` keyword.

It's already on stackoverflow: [[click]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894897/4029982)

Let me quote:

> It's because const implies internal linkage by default, so your "definition" isn't visible outside of the translation unit where it appears.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it by adding "extern" to the definition as well.