# C++ Referencing extern const within a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, extern

I am trying to use the constant int SIZE that is declared in the TaxConstants.hpp  namespace TAXCONSTANTS in other places in my project. When I try to compile, I get "undefined reference to 'SIZE' everywhere that SIZE is referenced.

file TaxConstants.hpp

```
#ifndef TaxConstants_hpp
#define TaxConstants_hpp


namespace TAXCONSTANTS
{
     extern const int SIZE = 4; // I have tried with and without extern
}

#endif //TAXCONSTANTS_HPP
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TaxConstants.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace TAXCONSTANTS;

int main()
{
extern const int SIZE;

// This is a struct defined in another file. It is a sample of my use for SIZE. I left out the #include above to simplify things. 
taxPayer payers[SIZE];  

//More code

return 0;
}
```

Additional info: this is a school project and my teach has made it a requirement to declare constants in the file TaxConstants.hpp in the namespace TAXCONSTANTS.

There are 5 files in total, the file with my functions is having the same undefined reference to SIZE error.

I have spent hours looking up similar explanations on the extern function and namespaces, but most of the suggestions are against doing this in the first place an offer another solution. I, unfortunately can not use them. Other errors people had were getting "multiple decorations" which I am not having.

## EDIT

See Brians explanation below for better detail.

What I needed to do was define

```
const int SIZE = 4;
```

within the TaxConstants.hpp file in namespace TAXCONSTANTS.

Then remove
'extern const int SIZE;'
from my main file and instead reference SIZE by TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE everywhere I wanted to use size.

This is basic namespace stuff that I completely forgot about.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does “extern const int n;” not work as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894698/why-does-extern-const-int-n-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with namespaces, but the issue of `extern const`.

Comment: You can see other posts using the search terms [stackoverflow c++ extern const](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+extern+const&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I finally figured it out right before checking back here. As Brian and AnT both state below, I was going about this wrong. Their explanations are better than I can write. I will add my resolution to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `SIZE` **without** the `extern` keyword, it will have internal linkage since it is `const`. You can refer to it in`main.cpp` as `TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE`. This is recommended since the compiler will be able to inline the value wherever `SIZE` is used.

If you define `SIZE` **with** the `extern` keyword, it will have external linkage and it should not be in a header, unless you want multiple definition errors. You should instead define it in a `.cpp` file which will be linked into the rest of the program. In this case there will be only one copy of `SIZE` in the entire program. You should avoid this approach (preferring instead the approach without `extern`) *unless* for some reason you actually need to have only one copy of `SIZE` in the entire program.

In both cases, `SIZE` will be a member of the `TAXCONSTANTS` namespace.

Your attempt to redeclare `SIZE` inside `main` does not do what you think it does! The following inside `main`:

```
extern const int SIZE;
```

actually has the effect of declaring `SIZE` in the global namespace. Since there is no definition of `SIZE` in the global namespace, you get undefined reference errors at link time. It is **not** the correct way to refer to the `SIZE` variable defined in `TAXCONSTANTS`.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out right before checking back here. You were write, I was going about it wrong and should have used TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems with the entire approach.

1. Your

   ```
   extern const int SIZE;
   ```

   in `main` is a declaration of `const int` object `SIZE` from global namespace - `::SIZE`. This `SIZE` has absolutely nothing to do with your `TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE`. Such global `::SIZE` object is not defined in your program, which is why you get "undefined reference" error.

   Since you already declared `TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE` in the header file, you don't need to redeclare `SIZE` again in `main`. Why are you doing this?

   Just remove the declaration from `main` and use `SIZE` from `TAXCONSTANTS` either through `using namespace TAXCONSTANTS` or by specifying a qualified name `TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE`.
2. The declaration you have in the header file is actually a *definition*. Including this header file into multiple translation units will result in another error: multiple definitions of the same object with external linkage.

   If you want to declare a global constant object, you have to keep a mere non-defining declaration in the header file

   ```
   namespace TAXCONSTANTS
   {
     extern const int SIZE; // declaration, not definition
   }
   ```

   and move the definition into one of implementation files

   ```
   namespace TAXCONSTANTS
   {
     extern const int SIZE = 4; // definition
   }
   ```
3. However, it appears that you are planning to use this constant as an Integral Constant Expression (as array size in array declaration). An `extern const int` constant declared without an initializer will not work for that purpose.

   Just forget about `extern` and declare a normal constant with internal linkage in the header file

   ```
   namespace TAXCONSTANTS
   {
     const int SIZE = 4; // definition with internal linkage
   }
   ```

   and then just use in everywhere it is needed

   ```
   using namespace TAXCONSTANTS;

   int main()
   {
     taxPayer payers[SIZE];  
     ...
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   // no 'using namespace TAXCONSTANTS;'

   int main()
   {
     taxPayer payers[TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE];  
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I was supposed to write it like TAXCONSTANTS::SIZE as you mentioned.