# private static const member variable in header vs const variable in cpp

Tags: c++, static, constants

Why should I declare a private `static const` variable in header (and initialize it in cpp) instead of just defining + declaring it in the cpp?

i.e.

---

case1.h

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
    private:
        static const MyType some_constant;
}
```

case1.cpp

```
const MyType MyClass::some_constant = ...;
```

---

case2.h

```
//No mention of some_constant at all
```

case2.cpp

```
const MyType some_constant = ...;
```

Assuming common c++ conventions are followed (1 header & cpp is only associated with 1 class, never `#include` .cpp file), in both cases, the variable is private to the class, both are initialized before the constructor is called, both provide the function of being a "static class local constant".

Is there any difference between the above two approaches? (And which one is preferable)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a `private` member, only the implementation of the class can access it.

Therefore, in the interests of not unnecessarily polluting your class definition, I'd be inclined to adopt the second approach.

You could go one step further and define it in an *anonymous namespace*:

```
namespace {
    const MyType some_constant = ...;
}
```

in that way, it is certainly localised to a single translation unit. Note however that your using `const` implies [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894698/why-does-extern-const-int-n-not-work-as-expected) by default. (Without `const`, the variable would be accessible by others using `extern`)

Comment: Aren't they local to the single translation unit anyway (without anonymous namespace)?  (assuming I never `#include case2.cpp`)

Comment: @Woofas: No, you could reach it with `extern`.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, you can't. As I know, `const` implies internal linkage by default.

Comment: @KonstantinT.: Interesting, I'll need to check that one. Unless SomeProgrammerDude is still watching this - they are an expert.

Comment: @Bathsheba Unless previously declared with `extern` then it should have internal linkage. Was wrong myself.

Comment: Seems that a deeper answer ought to emerge. I'll wiki this so anyone can contribute.