# c++ react to external #define

Tags: c++, include, header-files, preprocessor-directive

The glfw3-library can be made to include vulkan using a definition before the include:

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

i want to do a similar thing, but for debug vs non-debug-mode.
I tried the following:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#define DEBUG_ENABLED
#include "someFile.hpp"
```

someFile.hpp:

```cpp
#ifdef DEBUG_ENABLED
  std::vector<const char*> _debugExtensions = {
    VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME
  };
#endif
#ifndef DEBUG_ENABLED
  std::vector<const char*> _debugExtensions = {};
#endif
```

I checked if that 'passing of definitions' across the header-files worked, by printing the **size of the vector**, but **received zero** which indicates that the compiler didn't consider the DEBUG_ENABLED to be defined inside the someFile.hpp.

I then looked on stackoverflow to see how i could react to the definitions of an extern file, and found this post:

[Is it possible to use #define from other cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275950/is-it-possible-to-use-define-from-other-cpp-file)

The accepted answer there claims that

> Defines inside a source file aren't seen by other translation units. Implementation files are compiled separately.

My problem with this answer is that my experience tells me the contrary, as the **included glfw** mentioned above clearly **reacted to the GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN definition** i made.
How might one be able to achieve such behaviour (being able to react to definitions made in an extern source-file) ?

Comment: 1. How is `VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME` defined? 2. Can you show a [mcve] which will demonstrate which file (and how) did the size query?

Comment: You probably want to define your constant on the compilers command line - like `-Dfoo`..

Comment: I suspect not all cpp that include `someFile.hpp`, directly or indirectly defines the same thing.

Comment: I think you're confusing translation unit with source file, they're not the same thing. A translation unit is a source file after all the `#includes` have been replaced with the included files (and other preprocessing has been completed). Incidentally your example should have worked, so I think there's some other issue with your code.

Comment: Also, try marking your global `constexpr` and use `std::array` instead of vector. that will make use of constant initialization so it's immune to the order of initialization problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot i guess that might be the problem. Trying to implement a "minimal reproducible example" , i now stumbled upon multiple-definition compiler-errors..

Comment: @Angew it was a tough decision, but i decided to add the example you asked for in an answer, as it answers part of my question, and i felt that my findings might obscure the assumptions in my initial question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was asked to create a "minimal reproducable example".
This example showed that the problem really is a different one that i assumed.
 The example was successfull in **not** reproducing the error, but it helps to answer a part of my initial question.

**Don't consider this a good solution! This example is provided for clarification of cpp's behaviour, not as a solution to implement in a project!**

main.cpp:

```cpp
#define DEBUG_ENABLED
#include "someFile.hpp"

int main() {
    Test test = Test();
    test.doCount();

    return 0;
}
```

someFile.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
    #ifdef DEBUG_ENABLED
        std::vector<const char*> _debugExtensions = {
            "one",
            "two"
        };
    #endif
    #ifndef DEBUG_ENABLED
        std::vector<const char*> _debugExtensions = {};
    #endif

    void doCount();
};
```

someFile.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "someFile.hpp"

void Test::doCount() {
    printf("count: %lu", _debugExtensions.size());    
}
```

compiling, and running this with:

```sh
g++ -g main.cpp someFile.cpp -o out
./out
```

shows that **definitions** indeed get **preprocessor-directives** in **included header-files** to react accordingly.
The misbehaviour (as pointed out by comments) results from different includsions of the header, of which only a subset defines the DEBUG_ENABLED.
**The example here is still prone to that problem!!**

(credits to the people commenting)
**For a solution there are multiple possibilities:**

1. define the constant in question using your compiler, like so:

```sh
g++ -DDEBUG_ENABLED
```

2. make sure that the file(s) that have behaviour dependant on the definition of such a constant only get included from a single translation-unit, or that all translation-units are consistent regarding the definition of the constant. This pretty much rules out the possibility of keeping seperate .h(.hpp) and .cpp files.

Comment: Simple: once you include such a header file inconsistently in a program (i.e. once with the define, once without it), you have violated the One Definition Rule and as such your program is ill-formed (though no diagnostic required). In other words properties of valid C++ programs no longer apply to it, and it can thus do literally anything. That also includes working as expected in one example program and differently in a different program.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You *have* to define `DEBUG_ENABLED` in each and every file that include your class, or in none at all. You are still hitting ODR violation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot i know, i didn't provide this answer as a good solution, and i am aware of the problems, as i point out in my answer.. I still consider it to be answering part of my question, which was if definitions made in one file get consisted across includes.